# left outer join when one field null

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables t1,t2,t3 and its fields are given below

```
t1- t1id,name,age;
t2- t2id,t1id,date;
t3- t3id,t2id,time;
```

My Query is

```
select concat(t1.name,',',t2.date,',',t3.time) 
from t1 
left outer join t2 on t1.t1id=t2.t1id 
left inner join t3 on t2.t2id=t3.t2id
where t1.age= 12
```

Some times t2id doesn't present in t3 table at that time i need result as **name,date,** how is it possible in a **single Query**?

Comment: is that `left inner join` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ifnull()` to make `concat()` work even if some values are `null`

```
select concat(t1.name, ',', ifnull(it2.date, ''), ',', ifnull(t3.time,'')) 
from t1 
left outer join t2 on t1.t1id=t2.t1id 
left inner join t3 on t2.t2id=t3.t2id 
where t1.age= 12
```

Of use [CONCAT_WS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
select concat_ws(',', t1.name, it2.date, t3.time) 
from t1 
left outer join t2 on t1.t1id=t2.t1id 
left inner join t3 on t2.t2id=t3.t2id 
where t1.age= 12
```